# Can't import by library name, even though I have python setup.py develop it

Tags: python, import

I am running into a very strange python import problem. I wrote my own repo, and used a setup.py script to setup the import path, script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

__author__ = 'Shaun Rong'
__version__ = '0.1'
__maintainer__ = 'Shaun Rong'
__email__ = 'rongzq08@gmail.com'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(name='Quantomic',
          version=__version__,
          author="Ziqin (Shaun) Rong, Wenxuan Huang",
          author_email="rongzq08@mit.edu key01027@mit.edu",
          license="MIT License",
          packages=find_packages(),
          zip_safe=False)
```

I used `python setup.py develop` to run the codes. Now, however, I can't import the whole library by name **Quantomic**, any codes like

```
import Quantomic
```

or

```
from Quantomic import settings
```

will raise the error: `ImportError: No module named Quantomic`

I do have a `__init__.py` under the library root, and I checked `sys.path`, `/Users/shaunrong/Documents/projects/Quantomic` is in the path.

I do, however, can import using relative paths in any codes inside Quantomic, using like

```
import settings
```

will work OK.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? I am happy to provide more information upon request!

**UPDATE**

File/Folder structure looks like:

```
/Quantomic
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    /data
        __init__.py
        price.py
```

Comment: What does your file/folder structure look like

Comment: @BrendanAbel Just added an update

Comment: where is the setup file in this structure?

Comment: Oh sorry for missing it, it is in library root path, on the same level as settings.py. @BrendanAbel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setup.py` file is in the wrong directory.  Here is your folder structure

```
/Quantomic
    setup.py
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    /data
        __init__.py
        price.py
```

It should look like this

```
/Quantomic (can be named anything)
    setup.py
    /Quantomic
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        /data
            __init__.py
            price.py
```

When you last ran `setup.py`, it likely installed a `data` library into your python installation.  Or, because you used `develop`, it added the path above `data` to the pythonpath using a `pth` file in your python libs folder.